# How can I get the current URL or route in TWIG?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm very new to Symfony2 and I need to be able to test the current route in TWIG so I can display sub-menus in a template that's rendered like:

```
{% render "CPAdminBundle:Messages:sidebarMenu" %}
{% render "CPAdminBundle:Readings:sidebarMenu" %}
```

Within the sidebar templates I tried using the following but it throws an error:

```
path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'))
```

What's the correct way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: You should check out [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), it solves a lot of your menu-related problems.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The check you want to do doesn't belong to a view. Views should only take care of displaying, not doing any kind of logic.

Do the check in your controller and store it in a variable, pass this variable to your views, and the check the value of this variable in there.
If you want to do this on every action, give the [kernel.controller event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html) a look.

If you want to do it in the view anyway, simply compare `app.request.attributes.get('_route')` to the route you want. I don't understand why you put in `path()`.

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'my_route' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: the path was something that I got off of google but even If I try to print **{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}** the output says **_internal** and I can't seem to get the route name in the view which is what I need since I have like 10 twig templates that will go in my sidebar and display submenus according to the current route

Comment: What's the output of `$this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route')` in the controller?

Comment: It gives me the name of the current route just like I expect BUT I don't think I should do this in every controller I will have around 20, don't you think it should be checked in my sidebar template?

Comment: I know it's easier, but I find it really nasty. I've done some research and found out about the `kernel.controller` event, it might be what you need: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html. Use it to check the route before each action. ;)